# JWT/KONG: Cannot create JWTs with a shared secret

Tags: jwt, microservices, kong

I'm playing around KONG API gateway recently.

I want to sign each JWT with a secret that is shared in all micros. I need this because I want other micros to be able to decode given JWT and extract payload data and work upon it (e.g. _user_id_ field in the payload).

When I try to create a JWT for the first consumer, it works just fine. But when I try to create it for the second consumer I'm getting the following error:

`{u'secret': u"already exists with value 'secret'}`

I'm not exactly sure but I think KONG/JWT requires unique secret for each consumer to create a JWT. Is it possible to configure JWT plugin properly to be able to use shared secret to sign JWTs?

PS: I'm not entirely sure that using a shared secret is a good practice. If there is a better way to do this please let me know. Thanks!

- Kong version `v0.10.2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **private-public key**  signing method.
Create your JWT token with a *private key* and share the *public key* with all other microservices. Other microservices can verify the signature of the token by using the shared public key.

You can use RSA algorithm for generating the keys & signing the tokens. The private key should be only with the service which is generating the token.

Snippet for generating keys:

```
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
```

Snippet to generate JWT token. I am using JJwt API for generating the token:

```
Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(payload)
            .setExpiration(expiryDate)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, privateKey )
            .compact();
```

Snippet to verify the token with public key:

```
Jwts.parser() 
       .setSigningKey(publicKey )
       .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `key` in the JWT secret settings must be unique *across all consumers*, see upstream issue: https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/1512

There doesn't seem to exist a way to overcome this limitation right now with the JWT plugin. I myself struggle to see why this is the case.