# Correct Micro Service JWT flow

Tags: security, jwt, microservices

I am currently building out a micro service architecture and started with the auth server and client. I also wanted to confirm the best flow of authenticating a user with a token.

[image: flow]

In the above image. Step 3 is were I start getting confused.
I thought of 2 solutions to the problem.

One every api passes the token to the auth server and waits to get approval that the token stored inside matches the db and it is still valid.

Two is to include a secret phrase in the JWT token and just have the API service parse and check for itself if the token is valid.(The secret phrase would be so that if a hacker tried to fake a token and it parsed to a valid id somehow the phrase would be off without the secret code used to encrypt the token. Which I don't even know if it is possible. If not then I guess 2 would be the best course of action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hacker cannot create a valid `JWT token` if he does not know the the signing key. If he somehow manages to get that signing key it is reasonable to assume that he is able to get your "secret phrase" also.

About the checking: `JWT tokens` can be checked by the `API service` as they contain all the information needed (except the signing key that must be known by the API service). The expiration can be checked here also. Anyway, you also need the information stored inside the token, like user ID. You should do this if you want better scalability.

The only reason why you would need to check a `JWT token` against a third `Auth service` is to see if it has been invalidated; for this you need a central service although you could replicate the list of invalid tokens to all the `API services` for better resilience.

Answer (score 1):

1. You really don't have to forward the request to Auth-server to validate the JWT token. A **JWT token is like a bill note**, once it's signed it can be validated by anyone who is sharing the key.

   I would recommend you to **have an edge service** in front of all your API-services. The edge service either shares the key by which JWT token is signed by Auth service or has the public key to verify the signature.

   Once the signature is verified, the edge service can extract the required information from the token and add it to request header. Your downstream services can consume this information according to their need.
2. You can use Https to enforce that your request isn't intercepted by anyone over the network. In case, even if someone tries to mess up with the JWT token, the signature won't match and you can detect that. Please go through [JWT/KONG: Cannot create JWTs with a shared secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096281/jwt-kong-cannot-create-jwts-with-a-shared-secret/44368412#44368412) to know more about creating-parsing the JWT token with public-private keys.